# Perplexed on what is happening when sending binary image (jpg) data to AWS Lambda Backend through AWS API Gateway

Tags: python, reactjs, next.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Sorry in advanced if this a simple thing I have missed! I have successfully got this working with sending an image to AWS lambda from React through AWS API Gateway. I upload it to an s3 bucket in the same lambda function. Here is the React code:

```
// Init states in APP
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState();

// Input 
<input
  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"
  type="file"
  onChange={imageChange}
/>
...
...
// This function will be triggered when the file field change
const imageChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      setSelectedImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
};
...
...
// This function is triggered when a user clicks an accept button
async function submitToBackend() {

    // Here the image is a jpg
    setSelectedImage(e.target.files[0]);
   
    const backendResponse = await fetch(awsapigatewayurl, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/*",
      },
      body: selectedImage,
    })
    console.log(backendResponse)
}
```

On API Gateway I have lambda proxy passthrough enabled and have enabled binary image formats as shown

[Lambda Proxy Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFZIh.png)

[API Gateway Binary Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONQ6y.png)

Now here is the weird part...to me at least..
n my python backend code I have:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    key = 'test.jpg'    
    data = event['body']
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    image_filelike = io.BytesIO(decoded_data)

    # Create date folder and ignore if already created
    current_date = str(datetime.date.today())
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=(current_date + '/'))

    # Upload Image to S3
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(Bucket=BUCKET, 
                            Key='%s/%s' % (current_date, key), 
                            Fileobj=image_filelike)
```

But you see I have to do:

```
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
```

I thought I was going crazy so I went into postman, copied the curl command, and modified it to send binary data as shown from my command prompt:

```
curl --location --request PUT "apigatewayurl" \
--header "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
--data-binary "@/Users/user/Documents/IMG_7138.jpg"
```

And it is running fine.

I should have to base64 encode the data but from what I am seeing API Gateway or something along the chain is already doing it. Please let me know if I did this wrong and should do this a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so looking at this post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/handling-binary-data-using-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/ it looks like the encoding is determined based on the "content-type" header. You can see on the python backend code by using this code in the lambda function and viewing the results in the CloudWatch Logs:

print("isBase64Encoded: %s" % event['isBase64Encoded'])

Im going to leave the code and solution here incase anyone else needs help with this.